# Android: Copy a table layout from one Activity to another

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a table layout say TL1 in Activity 1 and table layout say TL2 in Activity 2.
I change some properties in TL1 and want to copy complete TL1 into TL2 when i open Activity 2.

Answer (score 0):

Given that table TL1 is presumably generated in Activity 1 based upon some backing data, can't you make changes to that backing data and then generate the table TL2 again in Activity 2, which will reflect the changes to the backing data? If your actual problem is how to persist the data so that it's accessible across Activities in your application, you could persist it to a SQLite DB or use a singleton or extend the Application class.

Your question is far too vague. You've not telling is what you mean exactly by 'change some properties'.